# Circular reference for typedef of function pointer in C

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers, circular-dependency

I would like to define a hash table with a swappable hash function.  The hash function would take a pointer to the hash table and the key to be hashed, returning an int like so:

```
typedef int (hash_function_t) (hashtable *, int);
```

where the hashtable stores a pointer to the function that will be used to hash keys:

```
typedef struct ht {
  size_t size;
  ...
  hash_function_t *hash_function;
} hashtable;
```

Unfortunately this creates a circular reference.

I need the pointer to the hashtable in the hash function definition, so I can do a modulus against the hashtable size, so it doesn't go past the max number of buckets.  I need the hash function in the hashtable so that I don't have to pass the hash function pointer all over the place.

I realise this will lead to code like:

```
*ht->hash_function (ht, key)
```

which is a little weird, but I'm fine with that.

Putting the typedefs in either order doesn't work.  Do I have to use the long definition in the hashtable and then do a typedef afterwards, or is there a better way?

This is all intended in straight C, no C++.  ANSI C solutions preferred!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can declare the structure before you use it in a definition. That tells the compiler that the structure exists, but it will be fully defined later. Something like this:

```
/* declare it first */
struct ht;

typedef int (hash_function_t) (struct ht *, int);

typedef struct ht {
  size_t size;
  ...
  hash_function_t *hash_function;
} hashtable;
```

Comment: Hah! Nice and simple. Didn't know you could declare and then 're-declare' a struct.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Now you do! :-) I had the same problem when I was learning C and implemented a linked lists...